# How to inherit a local java project to a playN project(HTML version)?

Tags: gwt, maven, playn

I want to add a local java project to my playN project? I am using maven structure for these projects. By adding the local project to the playN project as a maven dependency , I am able to run the java version of the project. But I get Gwt Compile Error when I compile the HTML version.

I have added the local project as inherit in the xml file of HTML project. But that didnt help. It still gave me an error "couldn't find .gwt.xml

Any thoughts?

Thanks in anticipation..

Comment: Can you post the compiler output associated with this error?

Comment: Hi, I got the solution for this. I have edited the question with the link to the answer.  Thank you..

Comment: Hi. You should post the solution as an answer and you can accept it :).

Comment: Hi Latcu, Thank You for the help. When I have added the solution, I was not having enough reputation to answer it. Now I could. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution from the following link: [link to the answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/playn/WFSkTH21pbU)